# Lemma about intersecting sets

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, co.combinatorics

I use the following Lemma and I wonder whether it is known in literature. If you look at the proof it feels like it should be known from combinatorics or extremal graph theory.

**Lemma.** Let $A$ be an $n$-element set and let $A_1,\ldots, A_n\subseteq A$ be a collection of sets, each of size at least $d$ such that $A=\bigcup_{1\leq i\leq n}A_i$. Let $d\leq s\leq n$. Then there exists a set $S\subseteq A$ of size $s$ such that $|A_i\cap S|\geq \left\lfloor sd/n\right\rfloor$ for at least $n/2$ of the $A_i$.

**Proof.** We may assume without loss of generality that every set $A_i$ has
  exactly $d$ elements. For each $i$, the number of subsets of $A$ of
  size $s$ including exactly $k$ elements of $A_i$ is
  $\binom{n-d}{s-k}\binom{d}{k}$ (choose $k$ elements of $A_i$ and
  $s-k$ elements of $A\setminus A_i$). Hence the number of subsets of
  $A$ of size $s$ including at least $k$ elements from $A_i$ is
  $\sum_{k\leq \ell}\binom{n-d}{s-\ell}\binom{d}{\ell}$.

For $k\leq d$ consider the bipartite graphs $G_k$, where one part
  consists of the $s$-element subsets of $A$ and the other part
  consists of the sets $A_i$. We introduce an edge between $(B, A_i)$
  if and only if $|B\cap A_i|\geq k$. The degree of $B$ in $G_k$
  corresponds to the number of $A_i$ that $B$ shares at least $k$
  elements with. As observed above, every $A_i$ has degree
  $\sum_{k\leq
    \ell}\binom{n-d}{s-\ell}\binom{d}{\ell}$. Hence $|E(G_k)|=n\cdot
  \sum_{k\leq \ell}\binom{n-d}{s-\ell}\binom{d}{\ell}$.  The average
  degree of a vertex $B$ in $G_k$ is $\frac{n\cdot\sum_{k\leq \ell}
    \binom{n-d}{s-\ell}\binom{d}{\ell}}{\binom{n}{s}}$ and there must
  be one vertex $S$ with at least this degree.

Observe that $\frac{\binom{n-d}{s-k}\binom{d}{k}}{\binom{n}{s}}$ is
  the probability mass function of a hypergeometric distribution with
  mean $\frac{ds}{n}$. Hence for
  $k=\left\lfloor\frac{ds}{n}\right\rfloor$ the above sum is greater
  than $1/2$ and hence $d(S)\geq n/2$ for this $k$. We conclude that
  $|A_i\cap S|=k=\left\lfloor\frac{ds}{n}\right\rfloor$ for at least
  $n/2$ of the $A_i$. $\hspace{4.5cm}\square$

Comment: there's probably a quick and dirty way of proving something along these lines using probabilistic method + markov inequality + poisson approximation, but I don't know if there's an official result of this kind.

Comment: How do you know that the probability that a hypergeometric random variable is larger than its mean is at least $1/2$? In other words, how do you know that the median is smaller than the mean?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, the combinatorial meaning of mean and median is not relevant here. I am simply looking for a vertex with degree at least $n/2$, hence for the smallest value of $k$ such that the sum exceeds $1/2$.